# why does height: auto not provide content area large enough to fit my content?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

When a user is logged out, the header shows a logo and a log-in form, which the header needs to be large enough to accommodate. When a user logs in, they see the full navigation on a header that no longer needs to be quite so large. I'd think that setting `height:auto` to "site-header" would accomplish this, but this just makes the form float over the header's bottom border.

html:

```
<header>
  <div class="site-header">
      <%= link_to full_title(yield(:title)), root_path, class: "logo" %>
      <nav>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to "Sell", new_item_path %>
        <%= link_to "FAQ", pages_faq_path %>
        <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path %>
        <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path %>
      <% end %>
    </nav>
    <div class="log-in">
      <% if !user_signed_in? %>
        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <div class="form">
            <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'peach' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form">
            <%= f.label :password %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'peach' %>
            <%= f.submit "LOG IN", class: 'button-functional' %><br>
            <%= render "devise/shared/forgotpass" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

css:

```
header {
    background-color: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    .site-header {
        margin: 0 2em;
        padding: 1em 0;
        height: auto;
        nav {
            float: right;
            a {
                margin-right: 2em;
            }
            a:last-child {
                margin-right: 0;
            }
        }
        .log-in {
            float: right;
            .form {
                float: left;
            }
            input {
                margin-right: 1em;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a Plunker with your example and it does fill the space.

https://plnkr.co/edit/QMiHzA89NZrDkpsrCefF

HTML

```
<header>
  <div class="site-header">
      <%= link_to full_title(yield(:title)), root_path, class: "logo" %>
      <nav>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to "Sell", new_item_path %>
        <%= link_to "FAQ", pages_faq_path %>
        <%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_registration_path %>
        <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path %>
      <% end %>
    </nav>
    <div class="log-in">
      <% if !user_signed_in? %>
        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
          <div class="form">
            <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'peach' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form">
            <%= f.label :password %><br />
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: 'peach' %>
            <%= f.submit "LOG IN", class: 'button-functional' %><br>
            <%= render "devise/shared/forgotpass" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
    background-color: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
    .site-header {
        margin: 0 2em;
        padding: 1em 0;
        height: auto;
        nav {
            float: right;
            a {
                margin-right: 2em;
            }
            a:last-child {
                margin-right: 0;
            }
        }
        .log-in {
            float: right;
            .form {
                float: left;
            }
            input {
                margin-right: 1em;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you have some other CSS messing around.

Comment: Fixed this a while back, but it was other css messing around.